# in VS2008, where do I configure the "Platform Target" for a (managed) C++ project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, managed-c++

In VS2008, I can specify that a C# assembly should target only the x86 platform by going to the project properties, clicking the "Build" section, and then setting the "Platform target" box.

What is the equivalent for an assembly written in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new platform:

- Select the **Build** menu.
- Select **Configuration Manager...** on the menu. The **Configuration Manager** dialog box opens.
- Drop down **Active solution platform**.
- Select **<New...>**. Then **New Solution Platform** dialog box opens.
- Drop down **Type or select the new platform**.
- Select **x64** from the list.
- Click **OK** in the dialog box to create the new platform.

Comment: Is that correct? The `Platform` is just a label and can be set to any valid word. The `PlatformTarget` is the actual architecture that will be targeted. (http://www.galaktor.net/2011/04/targeting-platforms-in-visual-studio.html)